# Android PrintedPdfDocument multipage PDF couse Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)

Tags: android, segmentation-fault

I am trying to create multipage PDF file on Android.
This is part of my code which cause a problem:

```
    document.finishPage(page);
    // new page
    pageNumber++;
    page = document.startPage(pageNumber-1);
    Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
    // draw new page
```

If I remove this code everything works fine, but all content of my PDF document is on one page.
I am using Nexus 7. Android SKD = 19 (Android version 4.4.4).

This is the error which I am getting randomly from time to time:

```
03-24 09:09:52.183      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
 ...
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ backtrace:
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ #00  pc 00077226  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ #01  pc 0007738f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ #02  pc 0001dbcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ #03  pc 0004e123  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398)
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ #04  pc 00026fe0  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ #05  pc 0002dfa0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ #06  pc 0002b638  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ #07  pc 0006057d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ #08  pc 000605a1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ #09  pc 00055287  /system/lib/libdvm.so
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ #10  pc 0000d170  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ #11  pc 0000d308  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
03-24 09:09:52.283      177-177/? I/DEBUG﹕ stack:
```

I used ndk-stack to check this lines, but I don't see anything useful:

```
********** Crash dump: **********
Build fingerprint: 'google/razor/flo:4.4.4/KTU84P/1227136:user/release-keys'
pid: 28425, tid: 28466, name: pool-1-thread-2  
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 000000e8
Stack frame #00  pc 00077226  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so: Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #01  pc 0007738f  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so: Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #02  pc 0001dbcc  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112): Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #03  pc 0004e123  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+398): Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #04  pc 00026fe0  /system/lib/libdvm.so: Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #05  pc 0002dfa0  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76): Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #06  pc 0002b638  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184): Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #07  pc 0006057d  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336): Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #08  pc 000605a1  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20): Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #09  pc 00055287  /system/lib/libdvm.so: Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #10  pc 0000d170  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72): Routine ??
??:0
Stack frame #11  pc 0000d308  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240): Routine ??
??:0
```

I tried to create empty white page document. Same problem.
Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the method canvas.drawBitmap(), do not forget to set the bitmap to be mutable. It might solve your issue.

```
bitmap_page = bitmap_page.copy(bitmap_page.getConfig(), true);
```

Comment: I am not doing that. But using BitmapDrawable instead of Bitmap solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of testing. Using BitmapDrawable instead of Bitmap solved the problem. I was used bitmap.recycle() always, but somehow BitmapDawable works better with memory recycling on low level and I am not sure why.

I hope this will help someone.